# Why is main thread a UI thread?

Tags: android, multithreading

Is there a reason why Android chose to make the main thread to be the UI thread?

Wouldn't it be easier to do all computation on the single off-thread or on a thread pool and then only if you want to draw something, then pass it to the UI Handler?

One might say that you can still off-load all work to a background thread and then post to the UI - but it's more about mindset. If it's off-UI thread by default, then the developer is more careful what to post on UI thread and what not.

I am not here to argue whether it was a valid choice or no - I am more interested in what could be the reasons why having main-thread to be UI thread by default?

Comment: Also - why downvote without a comment?

Answer (score 2):

> what could be the reasons why having main-thread to be UI thread by default?

Right now, as I write this, it is December 2017.

Android's architecture, with respect to the threading model, was created somewhere in the 2005-2007 timeframe. IOW, it was created over a decade ago.

Back then:

- Apps for mobile devices were very unsophisticated
- Mobile device CPUs were single-core, with that core operating at a tiny fraction of today's core speeds (e.g., 33MHz, 66MHz, 133MHz)
- Dalvik was purely interpreted (no JIT, no AOT)

The approach of having "one magic thread" is a typical embedded systems solution, when you are running on slow environments and the overhead of thread synchronization is too much (exacerbated by an interpreted language). Given the fact that we weren't trying to do too much in the apps, it was a reasonable choice. Creating multiple threads, passing control between them, and so forth, adds a fair bit of overhead, overhead that was unaffordable back then.

In [the Star Trek mirror universe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mirror_Universe), where the CPU speeds of 2005 were comparable to those of today, the mirror universe Android team probably made different decisions, possibly including more flexible threading for UI work. Plus, all of the men on the team would have sported goatees.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly, it's for getting more people to develop apps. If you just start with programming and the first thing you need to do, is to make a new UI-class, I think you would already be scared of the difficulty.

Answer (score 0):

It is a matter of synchronizing, the actions of the user and the results shown in the graphical interface must follow an strict order, and obviously it's easier to do it in a single UI thread

Answer (score 0):

Ease of programming.  You don't have to worry about synchroniation, locking, or anything else if by default all your work is being done on one thread.  Given the number of Android developers without formal CS training, that's probably a wise choice.

And actually as of v21, there is a separate render thread.  The Canvas passed to views in onDraw no longer draws, it accumulates draw commands, then puts that list of draw commands to a queue.  The render thread wakes every 16 ms (60 times a second) and actually draws that list of commands.

Answer (score 0):

I’d say it’s implemented that way because of:

1. Simplicity - you can do something simple and not computationally heavy/IO bound directly in main thread without any knowledge of threading at all.
2. Efficiency vs a model where *any* UI operation requires inter-thread communication. It’s more efficient to do a *tiny* computation and all the UI operations in one thread.